# Fake a single monitor with 2?

Tags: multiple-monitors

I don't really know how to ask the question without suggesting I have 2 monitors and want to put them in 'extended desktop' or 'duplicate' mode and lots of google searches keep sending me to pages on how to extend my desktop.

I've got 2 identical 1080p monitors. Full screen games and applications can full-screen on one but not both. Is there a way to install a virutal monitor device that the application will see as 3840x1080?

Comment: Not much experience with multiple monitors, but I know that this is a setting within the Graphics card control Panel. Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31704166/chrome-kiosk-or-fullscreen-in-extended-mode-screen-two-monitors

Comment: Can you explain sky extends doesn't work

Comment: @dave because it extends the desktop. the application is system aware enough that it sees monitor 1 and monitor 2. it wont fullscreen on 1 & 2. it will fullscreen on a SINGLE 3840x1080 but will not fullscreen on 2 1920x1080

Comment: `Windows` + `P` will bring up the side-bar to select how you want to display/project. Just choose 'Duplicate'.

Comment: @spikey_richie, i do not want to duplicate.

Comment: @BhavyaGupta, this kind of works. applications will see a single 3840x1080 but still only fullscreens to either the left or right side.

Comment: @parsecpython In your question you say " I have 2 monitors and want to put them in 'extended desktop' or 'duplicate' mode". Then you go on to say "@spikey_richie, i do not want to duplicate" in a comment. Which is it?

Comment: lol, ok, it's the wording. I'm saying, I don't know how to ask this question WITHOUT SUGGESTING that i want an extended desktop or duplicate. the key component is in caps